# How can I remove a row which is a duplicate for certain columns, and keep the one row with a specific value/character of a non-duplicate column

Tags: r, duplicates, row, conditional-statements

How can I remove a row which is a duplicate for certain columns, and keep the one row with a specific value/character of a non-duplicate column?

In other words:
How can I select which row to keep and the other remove with some duplicate columns

This is for a R data.frame.

I already tried:

Data.frame is X

```
 deduped.data <- unique( X[ , 1:5 ] )
```

problem: I cannot keep the column with non-duplicate row

```
X <- X %>% distinct()
```

problem: I cannot tell which row can be removed with duplicates in some columns

In the list of former questions I do not find answers: the information which row to keep/remove is available

```
deduped.data <- unique( X[ , 1:5 ] )
```

```
X <- X %>% distinct()
```

An example

Data.frame X:

Row 1: Gender: Male, Age: 20, Country: Italy

Row 2: Gender: Male, Age: 20, Country: France

Row 3 etc

I want to remove the duplicates of columns 1 and 2 and keep Country Italy. I expect that row 2 is being removed. `unique()` nor `distinct()` can do this as far as I can see.

Comment: Try `X %>% distinct(Gender, Age, .keep_all = TRUE)`. From `?distinct`: .keep_all 
If `TRUE`, keep all variables in `.data`. If a combination of `...` is not distinct, this keeps the first row of values.

Comment: Yes it worked! And with `X <- arrange(X, desc(country))` I could arrange that Italy was first, which I wanted to keep. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes duplicates, you can specify the column in the duplicated argument.
If you want to keep the non duplicates you can remove the !

`X <- X[, !duplicated(colnames(X))]`

Comment: Yes it worked! And with `X <- arrange(X, desc(country))` I could arrange that Italy was first, which I wanted to keep. Thanks!

Comment: Answ. of @Mark & @StevenBeaupr , & more info together - an overview: 

Dataframe `X <- data.frame(gender=c("male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "male", "female", "female"), 
                age=c(21, 21, 21, 21, 20, 33, 25, 20, 25, 40), 
                country=c("France", "France", "France", "France", "Italy", "France", "France", "France", "Italy", "Italy"))`
 
Arranging `X <- arrange(X, desc(country))`
Three options
`X[!duplicated(X[,1:2]),]`
or
`group_by(X, gender, age) %>% slice(1)`
or
`library(dplyr)`
`X %>% distinct(gender, age, .keep_all = TRUE)`